# Java 8 has introduce IntStream, LongStream and DoubleStream, why they have not added the CharStream and StringStream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Why Java 8 does not have StringStream and CharStream.

```
StringStream.of("String1","String2");

StringStream.concat(stream1,stream2);

StringStream.builder().add("String1").add("string2").accept("string3");
```

Comment: Because `String` and `char` streams behave differently from numeric streams?

Comment: What is the `String` "string" operation that you seek there? You can achieve all of those using `Stream<String>` as well, isn't it?

Comment: Therre is no need for StringStream.  `String` is already a reference type, so it doesn't need a pseudospecialization.  You can create a `Stream<String>`.

Comment: I am aware about it Mate,  would it be beneficial to add it?

Comment: No benefits whatsoever.

Comment: it's related to char in the form of Int, which is IntStream.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `char` stream for same reason there is no `byte` stream. All those specific stream added for optimization (no boxing/unboxing). `char` and `byte` internally represented as `int` so there will be no profit in adding them.

Of course they should add them for convenience, but they didn't.

There is no `String` stream because there is no reason for it. `String` is reference type, so normal stream will work with it just fine.

Comment: *Of course they should add them for convenience, but they didn't.* .. what convenience, could you elaborate?

Comment: @nullpointer when `IntStream` used for `byte` you have to convert values in most operations.